# I2C circuit resistance value

Tags: i2c, esp32

I have a question about I2C and esp32. when I started long time ago making circuit based on esp32 I think i have made a mistake on the pullup resistor by putting 4.7K on 5 volt on i2c lines.

the I2C lines work well I want to know why i did not burn esp32 SDA and SCL pin witch are 3.3 volt logic ?

if I am wrong what is the value for the resistor on 3.3volt.

Last question about slaves modules with are 5v do I need a level shifter on the i2c line in case of 3.3 volt resistor line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was a mistake to pull 3.3V IO pins to 5V with resistors.

It does not blow up because you can assume that MCU IO pins have built-in protection diodes to supply voltage to clamp excessive input voltages from doing damage.

And since you have resistors, they limit current which allow the protection diodes to work instead of damage due to excessive current.

Assuming the MCU supply is 3.3V, and the protection diodes start to conduct at about 0.5V above that, there will be 3.8V on IO pin and clamping current is only about 0.25mA. So this is why it did not burn.

There is no one true and correct value. There is a suitable range which depends on many things you are not mentioning. It depends on which speed you want to communicate, and how much total capacitance there is on bus, which depends on your wiring/cabling, bus length, number of devices on bus, how fast they are capable of communicating and in which mode, and in which limits they need to operate. So there are I2C specification limits, and limits imposed by the chips which may be within or outside I2C specs, and there is the limits imposed by the environment the chips are in, and that may also be within or outside of I2C specs.

So 4k7 to 3.3V could either work or not. It will be somewhat slower bus than 4k7 to 5V. It depends if any other module already has pull-ups or not. The total pull-up resistance must not be too strong or too weak, so that all chips are capable of reliably communicating at the speed you want to use, and you may need to do some tradeoffs.

And yes if you have devices with 5V I2C bus which are not compatible with 3.3V I2C bus then you need a level shifter.

Even if you have slave modules that take in 5V supply, it means nothing how they work internally, as they might still have internal 3.3V regulation and must not be connected to a 5V I2C bus.

Comment: Thanks  a lot  Justme for those  very good details  that make the point more clear .

Answer (score 0):

The worst case current from a supply voltage of 5 volts via a 4.7 kΩ resistor into **a pin** on your ESP32 will be approximately this value: -

$$\dfrac{\text{5 volts - 3.6 volts}}{4700} = \text{0.3 mA}$$

<sub>I've used 3.6 volts as an upper limit based on what the IC's protection diodes are likely to permit on a 3.3 volt supply.</sub>

If you read the data sheet for the ESP32, it should tell you that you can push a certain maximum current into a pin (possibly 0.5 mA to 5 mA) without causing damage.

Even if you are exceeding the maximum value, it doesn't mean a circuit won't work but, it can mean reduced lifetime for the IC.

My advice is to read the data sheet and see what the maximum current is.

> *if I am wrong what is the value for the resistor on 3.3volt*

I suspect it will be also 4.7 kΩ but, in reality it depends on your data rate and the bus capacitance.

> *Last question about slaves modules with are 5v do I need a level
> shifter on the i2c line in case of 3.3 volt resistor line.*

You might do but the devil is in the detail so, I can't say yay or nay.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your technical evaluation . I remenber when i made a pcb with a couple esp32 -imu 6050 at 400KHz for a boat  the result was really better at 5 volt  then 3.3 volt it's strange?

Comment: @KhalesNaim if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.